# How to save ML Kit models for face recognititon into device's persisted storage

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I have just started exploring Firebase ML Kit by Google to test out face recognition capabilities. I tried official samples and it's working well.

Though, according to it's official documentation, we can schedule an install time download of the ML models required, I need a way to pre-install the models into the Android device itself, so it could be utilized in my app whenever in Offline scenarios(w/o internet). 
If there is one, it would be of great help for my use case.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your dev workflow - what's the target audience for your app and how are you planning to distribute the app to them?

Comment: The target audience or the scenario to be precise here, is that, the app should work OFFLINE at all times and being able to compare duplicate images.

Comment: Understood, thanks. So based on the use case indicated, you are planning to bring your own model, right? That changes the answer. Your original question indicated you wanted to use the inbuilt face detection models. Pl confirm and I will update the answer.

Comment: I want to use inbuilt face detection models offered by MLKit , but, I need the flexibility to predownload/install those models into the distributed android device(persisted storage). Because of the following reason :

Comment: (contd.) In case the app is uninstalled and reinstalled by the user, there is no dependency left on the internet connection to re- download the models, as the app would be able to fetch the models from the persisted storage. Eg. HERE MAPS offline SDK works the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, working offline without downloading models even once is not supported for in-built APIs (like Face detection) at the moment. However, it is on our radar to support SDKs with models bundled. So please watch out for future announcements! In the mean time, you can use your own model that can be bundled with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, with ML Kit you cannot pre-install the face detection models on to the device in that manner. Like you mentioned, the models can be downloaded at install time, but the question indicates that you want beyond that - i.e. there is no internet during install time. If no internet, then the app cannot be downloaded and installed, which will limit your distribution.

**UPDATE**

[Confirmed from the comments that the user wants the models to be available offline even without downloading once during install time.]

As of now, that is not supported for built-in models like face detection.

However, if you use ***custom tflite models*** (i.e. bring your own model as opposed to using built-in models) with ML Kit then you can bundle it within your app when you build it on your desktop and distribute manually like you suggested. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) is the documentation for the custom model API which also contains links to quickstarter apps for Android / iOS.

Comment: The app needs to be distributed manually i.e. without play store. Hence, there is a need to pre-download and setup the models into the device.

Comment: @psanketi There is another piece of information I need. Since, I mentioned earlier that I need to compare multiple images and find possible duplicates among them. How am I supposed to do that, once, I have received the image data points from FirebaseVisionFace ,  like bounding box, face landmarks , tracking id, smiling probability,etc. I don't seem to find any code for the above requirement. If you want, I can start a new SO thread on this, because this is really important for the project.

Comment: @VaibhavMalik Identifying a duplicate image is out of scope of the ML Kit API at the moment. You have to define your own model, which is what we call "Custom model". You have to get some training data, and setup the ML training. It is totally fine to use the face features as input if it satisfies your case.

Comment: Minor correction: out of scope of ML Kit *Base* APIs (i.e. the in-built APIs). You can still use custom model APIs as I mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @psanketi, thanks for the response. Building custom models for identifying duplicate faces seems a hugely time consuming effort. An in my project requirement,  I was looking for something to save that time by using a third party library like ML Kit or OpenCV to begin with. Just to note, I tried OPenCV's android  sdk too, but its code didnt seem to work for my use case.  I'd really appreciate if you could guide me through something similar that might be useful for this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Not part of ML Kit, but I found this on searching face recognition: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition. Not sure if that satisfies your needs!

Comment: Thanks, this one seems interesting. looking into it.

Comment: isn't there a way to get firebase built-in .tflite files, personalize them and add them locally stored in assets folder? I mean are the built-in models not open-source/ available for download?